# Javascript UI library with easy bind to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looking for a free Javascript UI library which might allow for the following behaviour:

- create forms from JSON objects and bind changes to fields.

Creating forms from JSON isn't necessary, but library which supports binding well would be very useful here. By binding I mean:

- when object is created initial values there are interpolated to controls
- when control values change the properties change as well
- (optional) when values in the object change, values in controls change as well.

I only know jquery, but I don't think this library is particularly well-suited for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this one can help you:

[knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)